# Computing fractional linear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to determine how to compute the fractional linear transformation from ($0,1,\infty$) on to ($-1,-i,1$). I know how to do it when complex points are mapped to complex points. I am having trouble with the infinity. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If $\infty$ is mapped to $a\in \mathbb{C}$, look at transformations of the form $z \mapsto \dfrac{az + b}{z + d}$.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you form a system of equations? If the transformation is $\;f(z)=\cfrac{az+b}{cz+d}\;$ , then it must be:

$$\begin{align*}&\bullet\;f(0)=\frac bd=-1\implies b=-d\\{}\\
&\bullet\;f(1)=\frac{a+b}{c-b}=-i\implies a+b=ib-ic\\{}\\
&\bullet\;f(\infty)=\frac ac=1\implies a=c\end{align*}$$

So you can choose, for example, the transformation

$$f(z)=\frac{iz+1}{iz-1}$$

Comment: Just to address the OP's trouble with infinity, in the third equation for evaluating $f(\infty)$, remember to first divide the numerator and denominator of $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ by $z$.